# Web Api Content.ReadAsAsync method not found, but code compiles

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, resharper

I am using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to access a rest service. This code compiles and runs just fine:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = client.GetAsync(ServiceUrl + "/whatever").Result;
var content = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<StatusReport>().Result;
```

However the `ReadAsAsync` method is colored red in my IDE, and intellisense cannot find it. I have made sure to update all of my nuget packages. Referenced and added using statement for `System.Net.Http.Formatting`, but error persists (and resharper tells me the using statement is unused).

I am not sure if this is a problem with visual studio 2012, or with resharper 7. Sometimes restarting visual studio helps, and sometimes it doesn't. I suspect I may have some older version of some assembly referenced, or something like that, but I have updated everything I know how and the problem is still intermittent.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try clearing your resharper cache. *(ReSharper > Options > Environment > General > Clear Caches)*

HttpClient is new in 4.5 AFAIK and maybe your assemblies are cached from 4.0 or something?

Comment: I suspect that fixed it. I had tried looking for something like that, but couldn't find it. Thanks for making me look harder.

Comment: After clearing my caches, resharper knew to add the `using System.Net.Http` statement to my class for me, which fixed my issue.

Answer (score 14):

You must add reference from Nuget "ASP.NET Web API 2 Client". Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: Make sure the reference is added to your hosting project too. The code will compile if it is in a separate project that is referenced from your main project but will fail at runtime.